# Как идентифицировать пользователя на сайте, по мимо fingerprints?

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование, безопасность

Моя задача сделать идентификацию пользователя на страничке,
ip отметаем сразу т-к VPN
cookie тоже, тк почистил кеш, и вуаля, ты новый человек
fingerprints довольно сильный инструмент, но все же бывают ложные срабатывания
Я думал о создании js тяжелого кода и фиксировать время его выполнения, тк на каждой машине разная мощность итд.
Посоветуйте еще способы идентификации пользователей, есть группа недоброжелателей которая каждый раз создает новые аккаунты и продолжают заниматься грязными делами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автоматически со всех сайтов сразу почистить localStorage гораздо потруднее будет, чем куки, следовательно, чтобы усложнить работу тырнет-гангстерам, можно работать с ним.

Можно, например, формировать на сервере рандомную строку, кидать ее в базу приятных пользователей вместе с данными о нашем конкретном новозарегистрированном пользователе, а непосредственно на клиенте ставить ее в хранилище. Затем с каждым запросом отправлять ключ, чтобы проверять на сервере, существует ли он, соответствует ли он прикрепленному к сессии (тут хорош websocket) и нет ли его в базе неприятных пользователей. Если что-то не так - блокируем запрос и ругаем юзера.

При этом чтобы узнавать, когда юзер изменил ключ в storage или удалил его, можно реализовать две штуки: во-первых, отправлять крик о помощи на сервер в обработчике события `storage` (работает при любом изменении всегда, но можно любой обработчик удалить в консоли) - и тогда просить клиент снова поставить сохраненный и прикрепленный к сессии ключ в хранилище, предварительно перенаправив его в базу черного списка; во-вторых, пытаться отправлять этот ключ серверу каждую секунду-две, опять же, через сокет, чтобы сервер проверял, соответствует ли он первозданному (тут уж по производительности смотрите сами) - со всеми вышеуказанными вытекающими.
И да, повторюсь, стоит использовать websocket.

Ссылки, на всякий случай: [о WebSocket (сторона клиента)](https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket); [о WebSocket (сторона сервера - node.js)](https://socket.io/docs/); [о WebSocket (сторона сервера - php)](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman); [localStorage (мало ли)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил задумку. Если что вдруг, могу накидать схематично кодом

Comment: Большое спасибо, ваш ответ ОЧЕНЬ помог!